# Reloading a view in a viewWillAppear method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to reload the main view of a view controller from its XIB file in its viewWillAppear method? The method make significant changes to the view, which would be difficult to reverse. When the view controller gets pushed off the navigation stack, the method has to deal with a changed view. It would be much easier if I could just relax the view from the XIB. It seems that the Apple implementation assumes that the view will remain static, and can therefore be reused.

Comment: The view has been loaded already, otherwise it would not be appearing.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, you are free to load the view, modify the view however you want, etc. But it sounds like there may be a better solution. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Till: That's actually not strictly true. It's possible to receive a `-viewWillAppear:` method before the view is actually loaded. If you need to be sure the view is loaded in your implementation of `-viewWillAppear:` (e.g. if you want to access an outlet), just include `(void)self.view;` at the top of your implementation.

Comment: @KevinBallard doh, you are right - I somehow forgot about the lazy loading when commenting as I was thinking in an entire different direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can update large portions of your view in the -viewWillAppear. There is no stipulation what you can or can't update there.

Just make sure you account for everything, when you do. I have used -viewWillAppear to refresh my view with information, so you can use that to load an initialize what you need rather than -viewDidLoad.